# Passport JS OAuth2Strategy does't fire callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js

After updating my dependencies at service I'm creating I faced the issue that my Passport JS strategy, used along with OAuth2Strategy stoped working properly.

Here are the prerequisite:

- Node: `14.15.1`
- pnpm: `6.29.0`
- passport: `0.5.2`
- passport-oauth2 `1.6.1`
- express-session `1.17.2`

Strategy is initialised like follows:

```js
const passport = require('passport');
const config = require('../../../../config');
const OAuth2Strategy = require('passport-oauth2');
const axios = require('axios');

const MyStrategy = new OAuth2Strategy({
  // state: true,
  authorizationURL: config.myapi.authorizationURL,
  tokenURL: config.myapi.tokenURL,
  clientID: config.myapi.clientId,
  clientSecret: config.myapi.clientSecret,
  callbackURL: config.myapi.callbackURL,
  passReqToCallback: true,
}, () => {console.log('Fire!')}); // <- This line should be called, but it is not!


passport.use('oauth2', MyStrategy);
```

**Obviously, the part where fire is written should be replaced by callback function, but I replaced it for more cleaner code*

And routes go this way

```js
...


routes.get('/oauth/myapi', async (req, res, next) => {
  const authParams = {
      session: true,
      scope: 'read, create',
      state: req.csrfToken(),
    };
  return passport.authenticate('oauth', authParams,
    async (err, passportUser, info) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }

      if (passportUser) {
        const user = passportUser;
        user.token = passportUser.generateJWT();

        return res.json(user.toAuthJSON());
      }

      res.status(400).json({error: info});
    })(req, res, next);
});

routes.get('/oauth/myapi/callback',
  async (req, res, next) => {
    return passport.authenticate('oauth', {
      // failWithError: true,
      successRedirect: '/dashboard',
      failureRedirect: '/login/oauth/myapi/failed'
    })(req, res, next);
  });

...
```

So in a callback I do receive response from third service and it looks like this

```json
{
  "code":"2QoCKOzHQbCdJID4m...pwHv4M1RqUKjKF",
  "state":"dS9Gagcc-....a_yJ71YU",
  "user_id":"101"
}
```

But when callback route attempts to execute passport.authenticate I receive

> $ Error: Failed to obtain access token
> $ at /Users/number16/Documents/GitHub/Video-Mixer-Node/node_modules/.pnpm/passport-oauth2@1.6.1/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:178:49

Debugging didn't help much either.

It seems to me that I do something wrong or I should update my code as some breaking change might require.

The problem seems to be caused by switching from `0.4.1` to `0.5.2` passport

Please, provide me with suggestions on what might cause this issue and how to resolve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: After downgrading to passport-oauth2 v1.5.0 everything works fine! So the issue must be with  passport-oauth2 module

Comment: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-oauth2/issues/155#issuecomment-1053674221